# In ionic 2 input autofocus not support to IOS.How to resolve it?

Tags: ionic2

I has developed IOS app sing ionic 2.In my application input autofocus attribute not working but it work well in browser and i couldn't move my cursor in my input filed.

Comment: Did you already try with [this](https://mhartington.io/post/setting-input-focus/)?

Comment: yes,It return following error : Cannot read property 'setFocus' of undefined
    at Entry.focusInput (entry.ts:96)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (Entry.html:71)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11799)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13007)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:12595)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8773)